# Java, copy any file to a new root path

Tags: java, path, filesystems

I'll like to be able to copy any file to a relative path to my program. How do I make the path manipulation so it will work on any OS / file system?

Some example with Windows file system

```
c:\test.txt -> c:\myprogram\c\text.txt
c:\temp\test.txt -> c:\myprogram\c\temp\text.txt
d:\temp\test.txt -> c:\myprogram\d\temp\text.txt
```

EDIT : Another way to ask: How do I move any file to a specific folder, keeping as much of the original path as possible and avoid any collisions. The hard part is that 2 files can have the same path on Windows with different drive letters. And what about other file system?

EDIT2 : In general folks are to fast to downvote. If the users had paid a little attention they would have notice from the example, that the tricky part is the root name. I guess they downvoted, thinking this question was trivial. Delete this question or whatever, I do not care. Thanks to fge for a good answer.

Comment: Doing it in a cross filesystem way is impossible; Windows and Unix filesystems, for starters, don't have the same roots

Comment: For sure it is possible, but maybe not possible only using Path/File api.

Comment: I know it may not be easy, that is why I posted the question.

Comment: Well then see my answer

Comment: Why all the downvotes? If it wasn't clear please read the edit.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that in a portable way. Even with JSR 203.

A `Path` is two parts:

- a root (may be `null`);
- a list of name components.

One problem you have is with the root.

For Unix systems, for instance, if we take path `/foo/bar`, you have:

- root: `/`;
- name components: `foo`, `bar`.

On Windows, `c:\foo\bar` has parts:

- root: `c:`;
- name components: `foo`, `bar`.

Which means that in order to achieve what you want you'd have to inspect the root and mangle it before making it into a name component.

Therefore this will be a little of a hack... But here is a possibility:

```
// Supposes that the original path has a root
public static Path toNameComponents(final Path orig)
{
    final Path root = orig.getRoot();
    final Path components = root.relativize(orig);
    final Path mangledRoot = rootToComponents(root);
    return mangledRoot.resolve(components);
}
```

And your `rootToComponents()` method would then generate `c` out of `c:` and the empty path on Unix systems.

After that it's a matter of calling `.resolve()`.

---

Now, on to the real reason why you can't, ultimately, make it in a portable way: JSR 203 does not mandate that an absolute path has a root... This just happens to be the case on Windows and Unix filesystems since they are hierarchical.

Comment: Thanks. Surely i hoped this could be done more nicely. Very dangerous to handcraft this, which should be tested on all platforms.

Comment: @Stig you can always limit yourself to Windows and Unix; as to testing it, use [memoryfilesystem](https://github.com/marschall/memoryfilesystem), it supports both Windows paths and Unix paths.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time you won't have to do anything. Java deals with the various formats and when using `File.getPath`, it returns the path with your system's separator. If at some point you really need to know your OS's path separator, use `File.separator` or `System.getProperty("path.separator")`.

For example, all of these print `C:\JavaWork\Scala\Test\test.txt` :

```
System.out.println(new File("C:/JavaWork/Scala/Test/test.txt").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File("C:\\JavaWork\\Scala\\Test\\test.txt").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File("C://JavaWork//Scala//Test//test.txt").getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: "returns standardized path when using File.getPath" <-- no it doesn't. A `Path`'s name component separator is dependent on the `FileSystem` from which this `Path` is issued from. And on Windows filesystems this is a backslash.

Comment: @fge mm right, just verified. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a question about the file separator, which is fine abstracted away in the api.

Comment: @Stig then I don't get your question

Comment: The question could also have been: How do I move any file to a specific folder, keeping as much of the original path as possible without any collisions.